# deployment of react .env file in azure

Tags: deployment, .env

as with gitignore, we ignore .env file. so then how we deploy the .env file and get configuration value in code. Is there any specific approach for it?

I saw how to set up env value and use it locally, but my question is how could I deploy my env file in dev, prod...